# SQL fallback or c# datatable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, logic

say I have ten cars

columns for color, engine_size, type, make... etc there is 50 columns

I want to select for example:

SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE COLOR = 'red' AND ENGINE_SIZE = 'V8' AND TYPE = 'coupe' and MAKE = 'Ford' etc for all 50 columns...

but... and this where I'm stuck for the last week... I do not want the whole SELECT statement to come back empty when a condition is not met... I want it to fallback to whatever it could get...

for example if it only finds cars that are red and are Ford coupes but none are V8s then instead of coming back empty I want it to return the records that are red and coupes and Ford... and I have to do that for all 50 columns...

After trying and googling for a week I realise that SQL has no way to alter itself on the fly... you make a SELECT statement then it goes off and runs it... it has no way to go okay that part of the statement returns empty so I'll fall back to the bit that did work..

So now I'm thinking I need to do it with c# and write some ghastly code that keeps iterating through a datatable over and over gradually reducing it until it leaves what it could find.

This does not seem elegant and I'm wondering if there is a better way? I have not posted any of my sample code because nothing I've tried (ISNULL, IF EXISTS, etc) does anything close to what I want to achieve. I just get back nothing or everything.

To simplify what I'm saying with psuedocode:

If result != empty

select * where Color = 'red' and Type = 'coupe' and Make = 'Ford' etc (for 50 conditions)

else

select * where Color = 'red' and Type = 'coupe' and Make = 'Ford' etc (for 49 conditions)

... etc

but even this will fail because I would have to test for every possible combination of those 50 conditions... not just 50 one after another

This is my first time posting here so my apologies if I haven't explained myself very well.

Comment: This is your first time posting, so read [ask] and take the [tour].  The DB (nor  SQL) is going to know the precedance you want.  So SELECT on the minimum into a Datatable then apply successively more stringent row filters until you get just one...or none then back up one level

Comment: Plutonix well yes that is the conclusion I have reached also and the reason I'm asking the question because your answer means testing 50*50 possible combinations and I'm just not going to do that... my fallback position is to prioritise the conditions then delete all the rows that don't match one by one. I just wondered if I was overthinking it and there is another way and yes I did read the rules but my sample code does not work so doesn't apply and I haven't found any google links at all to what I'm trying to achieve but I've googled plenty...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` instead of `where`:

```
select top 1 c.*
from cars c
order by ((case when Color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) + 
          (case when Type = 'coupe' then 1 else 0 end) + 
          (case when Make = 'Ford' then 1 else 0 end) + 
          . . .
         ) desc;
```

You can, of course, adjust the "1"s to give weightings to the different features.

Comment: excellent I see what you're doing there and yes I see how that might work. I'll test it and get back to you. Thankyou.

Comment: I've tried to understand this but I've had no luck. Can you explain how this will work?

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah . . . This counts the number of matching conditions and orders the results by the total number of matches (with the most first).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm glad you explained it like that because even though I googled it I couldn't quite work out what it was doing. It seemed to do what I wanted on test data of 100 records but when I ran it over several thousand I didn't get what I expected. It is a stored procedure with 50 parameters though so I'm currently simplifying it to check the logic then I'll try again.